# How to exclude a specific pattern from regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a little trouble with a regular expression. I have the following string patterns

> 1. "Emily Watson (abril de 1897-)"
> 2. "Emaa William (california)".

I need to write a regex which should extract only "Emily Watson" from the 1st string and "Emaa William (california)" whole string from the 2nd string.

Basically my regex should omit the text along with braces if it is in the following pattern "month de year".
so far i have tried

```
(?'NAME'[\w]+\s*[\w]+\s*\([\w]+(?![\w]+\s*de\s*\d{4}-)\))
```

In above regex works fine for 2nd string i.e., "**Emaa William (california)"** 
but it's *not working* for my 1st string **"Emily Watson (abril de 1897-)"**.

In case of "Emily Watson (abril de 1897-)", I am not getting name i.e., Emily Watson.

Can any one please help me for how to exclude the first string of my problem.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with this one:

```
(?<NAME>.+\s\(\w+\)|.+\s(?=\(\w+\sde\s\d{4}-\)))
```

It returns

```
Emily Watson 
Emaa William (california)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should swap the negative lookahead with the match.

```
(?'NAME'[\w]+\s*[\w]+\s*\((?![\w]+\s*de\s*\d{4}-)[\w]+\))
```

This way, first you're checking if there's no `month de year` pattern between the parentheses, and *then* matching what *is* between the parentheses, while your version was first matching everything up to the last parenthesis and *then* checking if there was no `month de year` in the bit that was left.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your response. But even the interchange is not working, I am getting same output as before