# Exclude a specific pattern from Regex match

Tags: regex

Somewhat a continuation of my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054284/regex-matching-datetime-optional-second-half/) question:

I came across another pattern that I'd have to take care of, which looks something like this:

```
Tue 01/24/12 1/24/2012 2:56:25 PM
```

In which case I'd only want it to match the `1/24/2012 2:56:25 PM` portion.

My previous expression seems to match the above input on `01/24/12 1` or something similar.

I was able to make this work, for the most part, by using the following expression:

```
(?:\w\w\w (0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)?\d\d)? (0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)?\d\d((?: |\s*-\s*)(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)( AM| PM)?)?
```

The issue here is that I don't want to actually include the `Tue 01/24/12` bit in my match; I want to make sure that part does not match. I attempted to use a negative look ahead by adding the `?!` modifiers to the first non-capturing group, but it didn't quite do what I thought it'd do.

I've tried looking at similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876025/how-to-exclude-a-specific-pattern-from-regex) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597177/ommitting-a-specific-pattern-from-a-regex-statement), but the answers did not explain anything; they simply provided a working expression for that particular instance.

Comment: Please have a look at https://regex101.com/r/tR0yT3/1, I think you also want to capture `01/24/12` in your input string.

Comment: I'm trying to only capture the date starting at the second date (`1/24/2012` in the example), because after I capture it I'm converting it to a .NET datetime object.

Comment: Yes, but it is a separate match. Please have another look at https://regex101.com/r/tR0yT3/2 and the matches. Are you using C#? Please post your code.

Comment: Your regex will find 2 matches inside `01/24/12 1/24/2012 2:56:25 PM`. Otherwise, please reformulate the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are using (...) in your regex, you are creating capture Groups that returns those matches into groups.

In your case, you just need to create a group that contains your desired output, having that in mind i changed your regex a little and group $4 have your desired output:

```
(?:\w\w\w (0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)?\d\d)? ((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)?\d\d((?: |\s*-\s*)(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)( AM| PM)?))?
```

Tested on regexr.com:

[image]

To address your spacing matching issue, you need to include the space after the first(...)? group inside second (...)? group (I included as \s?), leaving you with:

```
(?:\w\w\w (0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)?\d\d)?(\s?(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)?\d\d((?: |\s*-\s*)(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)( AM| PM)?))
```

Also last group can't be (...)? anymore otherwise you would match infinity.

And You should also consider changing all your (...) groups to (?:...) if you do not need to capture them, leaving your desired output in $1

Comment: I was wondering if that'd be the best way to do it, but I wasn't quite sure if there was an easier way to just exclude a specific pattern. This one just about works, but it seems for some reason it's matching every space character in the text as well.

Comment: what do you mean by matching space characters? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I know what the problem is, but trying to think of a solution. The problem is the space after first(...)? group. and the second group is also a (...)? leaving you with a space match after finding first patern